# JComboBox content disappear once I select one

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a JCombobox whose content is populated this way:

```
List<MyClass> l = getList();
for(MyClass ll : l)
  combo.addItem(ll.toString());
combo.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

Everything's ok till I click on combo in order to show item list: when I click selected item disappears (but list appears) when I select an item on list whole combobox disappears!!
Why?

Comment: Show us more code. We cannot guess what is going on just from these 4 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was related to another problem I had and this answer 
[Panel components disappear when I minimize frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070911/panel-components-disappear-when-i-minimize-frame#comment16123679_12070911)

solved both!

Answer (score 1):

1. For `JComboBox`s (add, remove, manage)  `Items` to use is the `ComboBoxModel`.
2. `JComboBox` and its `Model` is based on arrays `Vector<>` or `Object[]`, since `Java2`.
3. All updates (`JComboBox` and its `Model`) must be done on `Event Dispatch Thread`.